# MySQL InnoDB Deleting Duplicate Rows - Time Out?

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

I have done a lot of looking and every solution I have tried appears to not work. I've removed the primary key and auto increment.

I have a database with roughly 260k rows. The schema looks like the following:
[schema] https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4MJX.jpg

It's a hosted MySQL innodb instance on Amazon RDS. When I try to execute the following command to delete the duplicate rows (tweet, username), I get a 2006 error - mysql server has gone away.

```
create temporary table tmpTable (id int);

insert  tmpTable
    (id)
select  id
from    rawTweets yt
where   exists
    (
    select  *
    from    rawTweets yt2
    where   yt2.tweet = yt.tweet
            and yt2.username = yt.username
            and yt2.id > yt.id
    );

DELETE FROM rawTweets USING rawTweets, tmpTable WHERE rawTweets.id=tmpTable.id
```

Any help would be appreciated!

-Matt

Comment: IGNORE is your Friend - you can create a uniqe composite index, if you using Mysql < 5.7.4, with the 2 field like **ALTER IGNORE TABLE db01 ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx1` (`tweet `,`username `)**

Comment: lol - i can't believe it was that simple. Took three seconds!

Comment: The proposed solution is very slow because of (1) lack of useful index, and (2) a slow algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be the following:

Create an identical table to the you have, but add a `unique index` on tweet and username and insert replace all rows.

```
CREATE TABLE unique_tweets LIKE tweets;
ALTER TABLE unique_tweets ADD UNIQUE INDEX `uniq_username_tweet` (`username`, `tweet`);
REPLACE INTO unique_tweets (SELECT * FROM tweets);
```

After this just rename the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Bernd Buffen had the correct answer in the comments:

ALTER IGNORE TABLE db01 ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1 (tweet ,username )

Comment: Extra advantage:  Immediately, future dups will be prevented from inserting.